# Find tables used from a VB.net application to remove unused tables

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, winforms

We are presently developing an application, let's call it `APP1`, which uses a SQL Database which have about 800 stored procedures, 600 tables, etc. `APP1` was originally created in order to replace another application, `APP0`, from which we do not have source code but only SQL tables, Stored Procedures, views, etc. Previous programers of `APP1` used some DB objects from this same database and added some other objects specific to `APP1` because it becomes bigger than `APP0`. And we do not need `APP0` anymore as `APP1` does all what we want, and more.

So, now, we are thinking about a way to find out which objects are used by `APP1` in order to remove objects which are **ONLY** used by `APP0`.

What is the best approach to discover all objects used by `APP1` without having to open every single class and form?

Once we will have a complete list of these objects, it will be easy to use a program we bought which detects all dependencies for all SQL Objects specified directly from SQL and remove objects which do not return from any dependencies. Any ideas of how I could get this list without having to go through all our program that have many, many, many classes and forms?

Thanks,

Note : I know, in a perfect world, all calls to PSs and tables should be in a DAL but in the case of the application we're presently working on ... this is not our case! Yippy! (sarcastic yippy) ;)

Note 2 : This application is not using any ORM. So all queries are directly using SqlCommand. So any call to any DB objects are in string format.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  If so, you should learn about the dependency system tables.

Comment: I'm pretty sure to do this in an automated fashion is an NP-complete problem. However, are there any assumptions you can make about how code interacts with the db? Is it via prepared statements, string-built queries, what?

Comment: Interesting question, you could look at the statistics for the tables and see when the last time they were updated.  If you've got a good test suite, you could just run a trace like suggested below.

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford: This is preaty much only SQLCommand so directly via string building. Some other objects are exclusivly used in SQL (From triggers, etc). There's only left tables from our APP1 to find out. Stored procedure were easy to find as they all starts by "SP_%". A quick search return all of them from visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you have all the Tables, Sprocs & etc from APP0. Presumably there is a BAK of them or you can grab the original SQL objects by installing APP0 on a fresh PC.

Then use [SQL Compare from RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) to compare the Database that APP1 uses to the original APP0 Database, then you can see which objects you've added and can strip out all the redundant APP0 db objects.

Comment: This is the program we are presently thinking to use as I'd alrealy used it in the past for another job. But, I ll check with my superiors tomorow about your bak idea. It's not crazy at all. I like that though... Hope we have it... Thanks for this Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

You could run a trace on the database whilst the application is in use. This is likely to create a rather large amount of data, but from that you can reduce it to the procedures and or SQL statements executed by your application.

Can you guarantee that you will, or can, use all the functionality? You might want to also run something like NCover to check how much of the application code you've exercised whilst using it.

Comment: I thought about this in another case, but I don't see how you could have any confidance in it. You might well have functions that are only run once a year, e.g. in an accounting system you could have year-end-closing. And there could be logic branches that just don't happen to get executed in any given set of runs, but which are required because they could happen someday.

Comment: I reckon a search through the source code would be better than the trace approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an easy answer, but here's how I'd attack it. I admit up front this would take a fair amount of time, so I'll readily yield to someone who has a better answer.

It's a two-step problem.

Step 1: Find all the dependencies within SQL. That is, find all the tables that are used to make views, and find all the tables and views that are used in stored procedures and functions. MS SQL server has a function to do this for you. With other DBs you could write some queries against information_schema (or whatever their proprietary equivalent is).

Step 2: Get a list of all the SQL statements and stored procedures executed from within your code. This should be relatively straightforward if you do not build SQL statements on the fly. Just search for all your SQLCommand objects and find what you set the query to. You could write a little program to scan your source and dump this out.

Then parse through this dump and make a list of referenced sprocs, tables, and views. Sort alphabetically and eliminate duplicates. Then add any tables or views referenced from sprocs and any tables referenced from views. Sort and eliminate duplicates again. Then you have your list.

If you do geneate SQL on the fly, I think the complexity level multiplies greatly. Then you have to work your way through code that generates SQL and pick out the table names. If there are places where table names are passed from function to function, this could get very hard. (I could imagine real nightmare scenarios, like you ask the user to type in a table name or you build a table name from pieces. Like, "dim tablename = if(dept="B17","accounting", "manufacturing") & "_" & year".)

Comment: sql server dependencies are very useful, but not definitive.  For instance, some dependencies might not be included in a stored proc that uses dynamic sql.

Comment: Hopefully, we do not generate dynamicaly our objects name via code. But, I'm affraid that a search for `SqlCommand` in the entire solution will results in a big, big number of results... I'll try it tomorow and get back with the number of results, just for fun ;) Just the idea to then, cut/remove `select` statement to only retrieve `from` statement give me big headaches... I'll need some cups of coffee :)

Comment: Well, there is about 1325 lines return for whole project when searching SqlCommand ...

Comment: As I said, it would be tedious, and if someone has a better idea, I'm just as interested as you are. If it's big enough, it could be worth writing a program to parse the list rather than doing it by hand. You have to weight the effort of the tedious labor versus the effort of writing and debugging. But then, once you had the program, you could use it again next time.